# Convert text to paragraph in Liquid Template

Tags: xhtml, template-engine, liquid, shopify

I'm trying to convert a raw string to html with the Liquid templating language. What I want to do is convert this:

```
Hello. This
is a text.

Please convert me.
```

into this:

```
<p>Hello. This<br />
is a text.</p>
<p>Please convert me.</p>
```

**What I tried**

```
{{ mytextvariable | newline_to_br | replace: "<br />\n<br />", "</p><p>" | replace: "<p></p>", "" | prepend: '<p>' | append: '</p>' }}
```

but this gives me (notice double `<br />`):

```
<p>Hello. This<br />
is a text.<br />
<br />
Please convert me.</p>
```

**Site note**

This will be used for a Shopify site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, Liquid does not support regular expressions, so the replace: `"<br />\n<br />"` will probably be interpreted literally.

Might be easier to implement as a new filter?

... something like this:

```
def newline_to_p_or_br(input)
  input.to_s.gsub(/(.*?)\n\n/, "<p>\1</p>").gsub(/\n/, "<br />\n")
end
```

Here is the definition of `newline_to_br` for reference:
http://rubydoc.info/gems/liquid/2.2.2/Liquid/StandardFilters:newline_to_br

Comment: Thanks! That would probably work. I should had been more specific. I'm using Liquid on Shopify. Don't think they allow me to do new filter. I'll try to research to see if they do.

Answer (score 2):

You're replacing new lines with break tags when using newline_to_br, so the first replacement won't replace anything, newlines are gone.

Comment: Is this in response to my tweet? ... I also tried `replace: "<br /><br />", "</p><p>"` instead of `replace: "<br />\n<br />", "</p><p>"` but it does not seem to work either.